# Light DOM styles "leaking" into Polymer component's shadow DOM

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I have a polymer web component which has a div named content, within the component.

I have noticed that if the host page has a style for `div.content` then it applies that style to my component!

This is an unexpected turn of events since web components are supposed to prevent light DOM styling from leaking into the component. In addition, I am using the following css rule which is supposed to prevent such a thing from happening:

```
:host {
   all: initial;
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add the code of the whole element and the HTML how you use it and add contentvto it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer by default doesn't use shadow-dom. It uses an approximation of it called [shady dom](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html), which doesn't provide style encapsulation and everything is dumped into *light* dom.

If you want to enable shadow dom by default, you can do so by using this [config](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings.html):

```
<script>
    window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {};
    window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow';
</script>
```

Comment: I just realized this exact thing for myself too.

Comment: I really don't understand why this is not the default.

Comment: Shadow DOM polyfill is really heavy. You can easily expect your load time to increase ~3x on browsers which don't support it natively(all browsers except chrome). 
That's IMO why polymer might've chosen to load lite version of polyfill i.e. webcomponents-lite.js by default.

Comment: @Abhinav this answer doesn't force Polymer to load the full shadow dom support. This flag only instructs Polymer to use the native Shadow DOM implementation provided by the browser if it exists  - so only in Chrome. It *might* be required to use the full ShadowDOM polyfill from web components but I haven't tested that.